# Suggestion for a eband local navigation simulation

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner, eband-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am working on a UAV ground maneuver with unforeseen obstacles in the airport, and I plan to use the eband_local_planner.

Do I need to ask for permission to use this package (This is an acadamic research).

With the designed Airport plan and UAV spec data, I have to build a simulation to test the feasibility of the elastic band method. To achieve this simulation what other package or tools will be require? And how do I visualized the simulation in ROS system??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240274/suggestion-for-a-eband-local-navigation-simulation/) by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With regards to legal permission, if you look at the source code for packages in their github repos, you will see they usually use a BSD license (at least all the packages I have looked at do). I'm by no means an expert in this topic and they may be some clauses I am not aware of (i.e. look into this yourself if it is a serious concern), but I do believe that means it is free to use for research purposes.

For simulation, I would suggest looking at [RVIZ](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz), [Gazebo](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo), and [Stage](http://wiki.ros.org/stage). RVIZ enables you to visualize data within ROS, while Gazebo and Stage are simulation platforms (with Gazebo being the more complex of the two). These are the most common tools used within the ROS world, but there is too much information about these to present here so I suggest looking into them on your own.

If you follow the simulation section in the [Turtlebot Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials) it provides a pretty simple example of simulating a Turtlebot in Stage and Gazebo, which may be helpful.

One last note about your choice of planner: I've tested both the `eband_local_planner` and the `teb_local_planner`, both of which are based on the elastic band method, and have found the `teb_local_planner` to be far better. It takes time into account and considers multiple trajectories simultaneously, which is more suitable for dynamic environments (such as an airport). It is quite well supported and has some excellent tutorials, so I suggest looking into it.

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1